# Angular CdkDrag element loses event listener after transferring item to a new list

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am using Angular's Drag Drop CDK to transfer items between two lists. One specific functionality I need is to be able to listen to the `cdkDrag` element's `started` `Subject` provided by the component API. However, after I transfer the item to a new list, I lose the event listener.

---

Example code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8lcqp

When moving an element such as `Fall Asleep` to the Done list, I log `started dragging` to the console. But if you try to move that element back to the first list, the event is not fired. What am I doing incorrectly?

---

To subscribe to the `started` event, I use `ViewChildren` to get a `QueryList` of `cdkDrag`. Within an `ngAfterViewInit()`, I loop through these drag elements and subscribe to the `started` event:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dragItems.forEach((drag) => {
    drag.started.subscribe((element) => {
      console.log('started dragging');
    })
  })
}
```

What is the correct way to track this event? Do I need to detect changes on the page and then re-loop through and resubscribe since the `cdkDrag` element is now in a different list? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you're right. Once you moved an item from one list to the other, it's attached to a new `CdkDrag` instance of the other list so your subscription stops receiving emissions. Worse than that, it seems to be a potential source of memory leaking, as the subscription is never torn down explicitly.

Your best shot is adding a listener directly on the draggable element:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of done"
     (cdkDragStarted)="_dragStartedHandler($event)" 
     cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
```

```js
_dragStartedHandler(element: CdkDragStart) {
  console.log("started dragging");
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right, I wonder if this is something I should submit as a bug to the Angular team? Anyways, I completely forgot about the HTML output events, so this actually works much better than what I was trying to do...thanks!